# how to make line charts by iterating pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have weekly time-series data that I want to make a weekly line chart using `matplotlib/seaborn`. To do so, I did aggregate given time series data correctly and tried to make plots, but the output was not correct to me. Essentially, in my data, columns are the list of countries, and the index is the weekly time index. What I wanted to do is, first iterate pandas columns by each country then group it by year and week, so I could have a weekly linechart for each countries. The way of aggregating my data is bit inefficient, which I assume gave me the problem. Can anyone suggest me possible way of doing this? Any way to get line chart by iterating pandas columns where grouping its time index? Any idea?

**my attempt and data**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/adamFlyn/7c96d7f7c05f16abcc39befcd74f5ca8/raw/8997332cd3cdec7610aeaa0300a1b85f9daafccb/prod_sales.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url, parse_dates=['date'])
df.drop(columns=['Unnamed: 0'], inplace=True)

df1_bf.index = pd.to_datetime(df1_bf.index,  errors="coerce")
df1_bf.index.name = 'date'
df1_bf.reset_index('date')
df1_bf['year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df1_bf.index).year
df1_bf['week'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df1_bf.index).week

for i in df1_bf.columns:
    df_grp = df1.groupby(['year', 'week'])[i].sum().unstack()
    fig,ax1 = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=1,squeeze=True,figsize=(16,10))
    for j in df_grp['year']:
        ax1.plot(df_grp.week, j, next(linecycler),linewidth=3)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.style.use('ggplot')
plt.xticks(rotation=0)
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

but I couldn't get the correct plot by attempting the above. Seems I might wrong with data aggregation part for making plot data. Can anyone suggest me possible way of making this right? any thoughts?

**desired output**

This is the example plot that I want to make. I want to iterate pandas columns then group its timeindex, so I want to get line chart of weekly time series for each country in loop.

[image]

how should I get this desired plot? Is there any way of doing this right with `matplotlib` or `seaborn`? Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `melt` your dataframe and then `groupby`. Then, use `Seaborn` to create a plot, passing the data, x, y and `hue`. Passing `hue` allows you to avoid looping and makes it a lot cleaner:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/adamFlyn/7c96d7f7c05f16abcc39befcd74f5ca8/raw/8997332cd3cdec7610aeaa0300a1b85f9daafccb/prod_sales.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url, parse_dates=['Unnamed: 0'])
df = df.rename({'Unnamed: 0' : 'date'}, axis=1)
df['year'] = df['date'].dt.year
df['week'] = df['date'].dt.week
df = df.melt(id_vars=['date','week','year'])
df = df.groupby(['year', 'week'], as_index=False)['value'].sum()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(squeeze=True,figsize=(16,10))
sns.lineplot(data=df, x='week', y='value', hue='year',linewidth=3)
plt.show()
```

[image]

This is the first and last 5 rows of `df` before plotting:

```
     year  week    value
0    2018     1   2268.0
1    2019     1  11196.0
2    2019     2      0.0
3    2019     3      0.0
4    2019     4      0.0
..    ...   ...      ...
100  2020    49  17111.0
101  2020    50  18203.0
102  2020    51  12787.0
103  2020    52  26245.0
104  2020    53  11772.0
```

Per your comment, you are looking for `relplot` and pass `kind='line'`. There are [all sorts of formatting parameters you can pass with `relplot` or you can search how to loop through the `axes` to make more changes](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/adamFlyn/7c96d7f7c05f16abcc39befcd74f5ca8/raw/8997332cd3cdec7610aeaa0300a1b85f9daafccb/prod_sales.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url, parse_dates=['Unnamed: 0'])
df = df.rename({'Unnamed: 0' : 'date'}, axis=1)
df['year'] = df['date'].dt.year
df['week'] = df['date'].dt.isocalendar().week
df = df.melt(id_vars=['date','week','year'], var_name='country')
df = df.loc[df['value'] < 3000].groupby(['country', 'year', 'week'], as_index=False)['value'].sum()
sns.relplot(data=df, x='week', y='value', hue='year', row='country', kind='line', facet_kws={'sharey': False, 'sharex': True})
df
```

[image]

Comment: can we iterate the columns so we could above plot for each country, like make above plot for `JAPAN`, `MEXICO`, ...? Plus, how can we remove the outliner in this time series data?

Comment: @Adam see my answer. I have also filtered out the outlier with `df.loc[df['value'] < 3000]`. This should give you the jist if you could kindly accept the solution and open another question referencing back to this one if you have any more questions.

Comment: thanks, I am not quite sure about using `replot`. Can we do this using `matplotlib` instead? plot for each country is not sharing x-axis, so there would be seperate plot and I could customize line and color and so on. I guess we could do this with `matplotlib`. Could you suggest me how to do this? Thank you!

Comment: @Adam you can pass `sharex=True`. In the answer, I have linked to the documentation which shows the various parameters you can use. EDIT, theyu don't have a `sharex` parameter. You can easily loop through the `axes`. one sec.

Comment: there is no parameter called `sharex`.  seems `replot` get `sharex=True` by default. Just for learning, could you show `matplotlib` approach in the answer thread? Thank you!

Comment: @Adam you can use `sns.relplot(data=df, x='week', y='value', hue='year', row='country', kind='line', facet_kws={'sharey': False, 'sharex': True})` And, I wouldn't use `matplotlib`. For the one graph I would use `matplotlib`, but for the multiple graphs, I would use `seaborn`. Sorry, I have to run.

Comment: @yes, this worked, good to know this trick. How can make this with `matplotlib` instead?

Comment: @Adam glad it worked. You can use `seaborn` and `matplotlib` together. `seaborn` works on top of `matplotlib`. Iteratively asking for updated versions of answer is highly discouraged, particulary for `seaborn` / `matplotlib`. These plot questions can get extremely detailed. I would encourage you to create a new question and please accept this as answer. Someone else from the community will probably be able to answer it, as I may not be on StackOverflow until next week. Thank you!